# How to add next/back buttons to Notepad 3 on android?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-listview

I am trying to add next/back buttons on NoteEdit activity ([Notepad Exercise 3](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/notepad/notepad-ex3.html) code).
I've created options menu and added two buttons there. In `onOptionsItemSelected` I've written the following:

```
case R.id.movie_menu_previous:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MovieView.class);
        i.putExtra(MoviesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId+1);
        startActivity(i);
        return true;
case R.id.movie_menu_next:
        Intent i = new Intent(this, MovieView.class);
        i.putExtra(MoviesDbAdapter.KEY_ROWID, mRowId+1);
        startActivity(i);
    return true;
```

But the problem is that number of rows is limited. So, if user presses Next on the last row, I am getting FC.
How can I know that this is first row? last row? (I've modified the initial code and now in the database I have many records, but not all of them are shown in `ListView`)
And, will not it be better to change logic of `populateFields` function and call it instead of creation new activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've overridden `populatefields` function and added there the following:

```
mRowId = mDbHelper.getNextRecord(1, mRowId);
```

And here is the code of getNextRecord function:

```
public long getNextRecord(int next, long rowId) {
    long nextRowId = 0;
    Cursor mCursor = mDb.query(DATABASE_TABLE, new String[] {KEY_ROWID,KEY_TITLE}, KEY_TITLE + "!=\"\"", null, null, null, null);
    if (mCursor.moveToFirst()) {
        do {
            if (mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID)) == rowId) {
                if (!mCursor.move(next)) {
                    // first (-1) or last position
                    if (mCursor.getPosition() == -1) {
                        mCursor.moveToLast();
                    } else {
                        mCursor.moveToFirst();
                    }
                }
                nextRowId = mCursor.getLong(mCursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(KEY_ROWID));
                break;
            }
        } while (mCursor.moveToNext());
    }
        mCursor.close();
    return nextRowId;
}
```